# Having only one of two custom cells (row and section) show ripple ListSelector

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

At the moment, I have a ListView which uses two custom XML cells, a standard row, and a section row to break up the rows into categories.

Both use backgrounds, so for the ripple selection to appear, I used:

```
android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
```

But this causes my will be unselectable section rows to display the ripple effect when clicked upon. I wish to keep the ripple effect for the standard rows, but not for the section rows. Is this possible?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer after some time. In my CustomListAdpater, the part where the codes checks which type the row is (standard, section) I added a couple of lines as seen below:

```
convertView.setOnClickListener(null);
convertView.setOnLongClickListener(null);
convertView.setLongClickable(false);
```

So now it looks like:

```
ViewHolder mainText = new ViewHolder();

convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_section_row, parent, false);

convertView.setOnClickListener(null);
convertView.setOnLongClickListener(null);
convertView.setLongClickable(false);

mainText.textView = (TextView) 
convertView.findViewById(R.id.textSeparator);
mainText.textView.setText("Wednesday, 10 March");

convertView.setTag(mainText);
break;
```